# Fill cell in a QTreeView with a different color and QDiagCrossPattern with a different color

Tags: c++, qt

I am using a QTreeView in which I want particular cells to have a background color as lets say blue and have a Qt::DiagCrossPattern with gray color on it.
And it would be preferable to have this implementation in the Model::data and not in paint. 
Is there any way to achieve this via Qt::BackgroundRole in the Model::Data itself?
I tried doing this :

```
Model::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
case Qt::BackgroundRole:
{
QColor backgroundcolor = Qt::blue; 
return QBrush(backgroundcolor, Qt::DiagCrossPattern);
}
}
```

But this keeps the background color transparent and diagcrosspattern lines are blue which is not the requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a texture (e.g. a `QPixamp`) and use it in the `QBrush`

See [QBrush(const QPixmap&)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbrush.html#QBrush-6)

For the texture, you can load an image or create it using `QPainter`

```
QPixmap pixmap(16, 16);
pixmap.fill(QColor(0, 0, 255));
QPainter painter(&pixmap);
painter.fillRect(pixmap.rect(), QBrush(QColor(128, 128, 128), Qt::DiagCrossPattern));
```